# Multiple times rendered collection in Backbone app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my ongoing self thought process by building [my simple blog app](http://jsfiddle.net/farukscan/0zct5p3w/) I am finding solutions to problems and encountering new ones.

Now successfully routing to a second view from a first one, and page is populated by the new views html.

Successfully save to the db new posts from second view, which is a form to add new posts.

First problem is:
In the first view I have the posts rendered five times, in order. There is not any js console messages. I have saved those posts each only one time from the second view, which is my postformview for saving posts.

Second problem is: From second view to the first view when navigated with the browser back button no posts rendered into page only the headers etc in one of the templates of this page is rendered.

What can be the issue here which I miss?

first view:

```
    var postsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: new postsCollection(),//! The Collection may be created to use in view. with new Coolectionname(). SOLVED it must be created, this attr is not suffcent and is not crating it.
    template1: _.template( $('#postsListTemplate').html() ),//!!!Once forgot .html().
    template2: _.template( $('#postsListItemTemplate').html() ),
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.collection.on('add', this.renderPostsListItem, this);
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template1() );//!this.el or this.$el. (each) or (each.toJSON()). SOLVED: use this.$el alongside el: a string, without $().
        return this;
        //* return this in every views render: if you want to chain el to render() of the view, for example in router  while pcaing the rendered views el into DOM.
    },

    renderPostsListItem: function(){
        console.log("view method renderPostsListItem have been reached.");
        this.ul = 'ul';
        this.collection.forEach(function(each){
            $(this.ul).append( this.template2( each.attributes ) );
            }, this);
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        "click a": 'toPostFormRoute'
    },
    toPostFormRoute: function(e){
        console.log("view method toPostFormRoute have been reached.");

        e.preventDefault();
        Backbone.history.navigate( '/posts/postform' , {trigger: true});
        console.log("view method toPostFormRoute have been reached.");
    }
});
```

router:

```
//Define Client-Side Routes
var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    el: 'body',

    routes: {
        'posts/postform': 'viewPostForm',
        '': 'viewPosts'
    },

    viewPosts: function(){
        console.log("router method viewPosts have been reached.");

        this.postslistview = new postsListView();
        $(this.el).html( this.postslistview.render().el );
    },

    viewPostForm: function(){
        console.log("router method viewPostForm have been reached.");
        this.postformview = new postFormView();
        $(this.el).html( this.postformview.render().el );
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Variation. adding each model when an add event fired  y passing the model added to the method and rendering template only with it, appending only it. not iterating through collection them all.

This solves first issue but not the second issue. What can be the specific issue for this?

code fragment from the first view:

```
 initialize: function(){
            this.collection.fetch();
            this.collection.on('add', this.renderPostsListItem, this);
        },
renderPostsListItem: function(model){
        console.log("view method renderPostsListItem have been reached.");
            this.$el.find('ul').append( this.template2(model.toJSON()) );
        return this;
    },
```

Comment: You keep adding views for all of the models in the collection every time a model is added. Is that on purpose?

Comment: for second issue, show your router & first view code.

Answer (score 0):

***Issue :***

When a new item/model is added to the collection, all the items present in the collection are rendered/appended to the view's EL instead of only the newly added.

*Root Cause :*

```
renderPostsListItem#3
```

*Solution*

```
renderPostsListItem: function(model){
    console.log("view method renderPostsListItem have been reached.");
    this.collection.forEach(function(each){
        this.$el.find('ul').append( this.template2(model.toJSON()) );
        }, this);
    return this;
},
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add

Comment: For the first issue: I have realised it but I think the look of the page should be like that; every added model fires the method and it renders the view by appending each model in the collection upto moment pushed into template. so the number of the rendered models is incremented by one. Why all of them is rendered in each undesired repetition. Models are being added one by one and 'add' is fired each time, right? I had solved the first issue by changing event listener to collection form 'add' to 'sync'. Your code has solved the second issue as well.

Comment: Wait a moment your code fires method on every 'add' and this causes repetition also. Listen to should be changed  to listen to 'sync', and triggered method does not need an argument as model and each.toJSON() should be passed to the template function. Can you edit your answer?

Comment: `initialize: function(){
  this.collection.fetch();
  this.collection.on('add', this.renderPostsListItem, this);
 },`

            `renderPostsListItem: function(model){
     console.log("view method renderPostsListItem have been reached.");
         this.$el.find('ul').append( this.template2(model.toJSON()) );
     return this;
 },`
should also work but I did not understand why it does not solve second issue while it scuccessfully solves first issue?

Comment: where are the posts saved ? and from where is the collection fetched ? Can you confirm that collection.fetch() is actually returning a non-empty collection ?

Comment: Problem have been solved. I will reflect it here. the third comment, with codes, has the thing I still did not understand. I have put all the code on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farukscan/0zct5p3w/) by the way for your questions, can you check it out there.